# Size of 3-SAT assignments

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, sat

Let $F(N,M)$ be the set of [3-SAT formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) with $N$ variables and $M$ clauses.  For a given formula $f\in F(N,M)$, we can ask for the set $s_f$ of truth assignments that satisfy $f$.  (If $f$ is unsatisfiable, then $s_f$ will be the empty set.) Let's consider all the possible sets of truth assignments that we can specify by these formulas:
$$S(N,M)=\{s_f | f\in F(N,M)\}$$
Finally, define the size of this set of sets as
$$T(N,M) = |S(N,M)|$$

If we keep our variables fixed and keep adding clauses, we can express more complicated sets $s_f$.  I had always assumed that for some sufficiently large $M$, I could express any set of assignments. In other words, if we define
$$W(N)=\max_M T(N,M)$$
then I had assumed that
$$W(N)=2^{2^N}$$

However, this is not true; there are forbidden sets of assignments that cannot be expressed by 3-SAT.  This is easy to see-- each clause of a 3-SAT formula forbids 1/8th of the possible truth assignments, so we cannot have a set of assignments with at least one but less than 1/8th of the assignments forbidden.  For example, there is no $f\in F(4,M)$ such that $|s_f|=15$, regardless of how big we make $M$.  It follows that for $N>3$,
$$W(N) < 2^{2^N}$$

But that might just be the tip of the iceberg in terms of "missing" sets.  Define the size of the missing sets as:
$$V(N) = 2^{2^N} - W(N)$$
Question: How does $V(N)$ grow with $N$?  Or, equivalently, how does $W(N)$ grow with $N$?

(There's a second question about growth in $N$ and $M$ that I will ask separately.)

Edit #1: Although it's probably not helpful for the asymptotics, I enumerated $T(N,M)$ to convergence for small $N$. For $N<6$, the calculation is complete (i.e., the set does not grow by adding more clauses). Modulo programming bugs, I get:

| $T(N,M)$ | $M=0$ | $M=1$ | $M=2$ | $M=3$ | $M=4$ | $M=5$ | $M=6$ | $M=7$ | $M=8$ | $M=9$ | $M=10$ | $M=11$ | $M=12$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $N=1$ | 1 | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| $N=2$ | 1 | 9 | 16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| $N=3$ | 1 | 27 | 158 | 246 | 256 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| $N=4$ | 1 | 65 | 1,430 | 11,334 | 31,402 | 41,746 | 43,074 | 43,138 | 43,146 |  |  |  |  |
| $N=5$ | 1 | 131 | 6,992 | 193,872 | 2,766,512 | 19,160,896 | 62,432,832 | 103,652,512 | 117,960,004 | 120,336,724 | 120,509,092 | 120,510,052 | 120,510,132 |
| $N=6$ | 1 | 233 | 24,084 | 1,459,044 | 56,328,304 | 1,382,172,232 | ? |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| $N=7$ | 1 | 379 | 66,586 | 7,224,786 | 538,779,796 | ? |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Note that $T(N,0)=1$ and
$$T(N,1)=8{M \choose 3} + 4{M \choose 2} + 2{M\choose 1} + 1$$

For $N\leq 5$ we have convergence; the summarized results are:

| $W(N)$ | $2^{2^N}$ |
| --- | --- |
| $W(1)$=4 | 4 |
| $W(2)$=16 | 16 |
| $W(3)$=256 | 256 |
| $W(4)$=43,146 | 65,536 |
| $W(5)$=120,510,132 | 4,294,967,296 |

Edit #2: We can translate the "each clause forbids 1/8th of the truth assignments" observation above into an explicit bound using large deviation theory.  Let $P$ be a Bernoulli distribution with probability 7/8 of zero and $H(P)$ be its entropy.  Then, ignoring sub-exponential terms:
$$V(N) \geq 2^{H(P)\times N} = 2^{0.543564443... \times N}$$

Comment: Trivially $W(N) \leq 2^{\sum_{k = 0}^3 {2N \choose k}}$, which is much smaller than $2^{2^N}$ for large $N$.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov That is an excellent point!  I guess that's about $2^{(4/3)N^3}$ asymptotically.